# If the "to" in "Please sign in to https://facebook.com to view my photos." is wrong, what's the reason?

Tags: prepositions

I have this sentence: `Please sign in to https://facebook.com to view my photos.`.

Since `https://facebook.com` is a URL, it seems that it is a location. Replacing `to` with `at` sounds more appropriate if it's indeed a location. However, in case `to` is wrong, is it because `https://facebook.com` is a location? If `to` is also correct, what is the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: I would use "at", since it refers to a location (some web server or your computer, depending on how you look at it) as you said. But "To sign in, please *go to* ..." would be OK.